# Extjs-panel afterlayout issue

Tags: extjs

hi i have a panel im doing some action on panel afterlayout but im facing a problem in panel afterlayout it seems to fire when its not suppose to..like when a broser goes out of focus..why does it happen is there a way to stop it..

Comment: Please post the code here. Did  you try panelVariable.doLayout(); ?

Comment: Like Swar said, post your code here. Are you doing your actions is a event handler that is hooked up to the afterlayout event or are you redefining the AfterLayout function in your own class?

Comment: why has this question got an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I too faced same issue. **afterlayout** event is getting fired multiple times. This causes the performance down also.

The workaround (I believe this is not the solution.. but only workaround.. and I consider it as a bug....) is to use also buffer : 1

Using this
Code:

```
vObjPanel.on("afterlayout", markInvalidFields, vObjPanel, {single: true, buffer : 1})
```

or

```
listeners: {
    single: true,
    buffer : 1,
    afterlayout: 'onAfterLayoutAvailabilityGrid'
}
```

Please see the more discussion in sencha forum https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?78630-afterlayout-event-too-much-call